# Is it strictly necessary or advantageous to separate the ServiceContract and the implementation of a WCF Service?

Tags: .net, wcf

Today I began toying with WCF. One thing I noticed is that, by default, Visual Studio defines a WCF service in terms of a `ServiceContract`, which is an interface; and a class actually implementing that interface. However, in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx), I found the following snippet (what the code actually does is irrelevant):

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial class BookmarkService
{
    // in-memory resource collections
    Dictionary<string, User> users = new Dictionary<string, User>();
    Dictionary<string, Bookmark> bookmarks = new Dictionary<string, Bookmark>();
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
    [OperationContract]
    User GetUserAccount(string username)
    {
        // ...
```

So, is it necessary to separate a WCF Service's interface from its implementation? If it is not strictly necessary to do that, does it offer any advantages versus not doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to separate out the service contract as an interface - as you've seen.

But it's highly advisable to do so:

- you get more flexibility
- you get better testability

WCF services are perfectly suited for using interfaces to define the **contract** which the service guarantees, and separating that from the actual implementation.

Also, with having contracts as interfaces, you can have a single service implementation class implementing several service interfaces - yet another degree of flexibility.